# How do I get hex() to print the full hex value in Python?

Tags: python, hex

Say I have 2 hex values that were taken in from keyboard input.

E.g. val1 = 0x000000 and val2 = 0xFF0000

and I do,

```
print(hex(val1)) 
print(hex(val2))
```

I get the right output for val2 but val1 is just 0x0, how do I get it to print the whole value?

By whole value, I mean, if the inputted value is 0x000000, I want to output the value as 0x000000 and not 0x0.

Comment: Exactly what do you want? `0x0` and `0x000000` are equal.

Comment: I understand that they are equal, it's just that the test cases for some programming challenge I am doing is asking for the full value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain **exactly** what do you want to print. What is the "full value"?

Comment: Do you just need a string representation of the full value?

Comment: If so `'0x{:06x}'.format(val1)`

Comment: @chrisz Thanks, that helped.

Comment: Why did you convert the user input into integers if you wanted the original strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad the hex value to the specified number of digits by using the `ljust` method.

Whenever the string is less than the specified width, it'll append the specified filler character to extend it.

In your example example, `hex(0x0).ljust(8, '0') == "0x000000"`.
Strings that are already long enough are preserved so that 0xFF0000 will still work.

```
print(hex(0x000000).ljust(8, '0')) # Prints 0x000000
print(hex(0xFF0000).ljust(8, '0')) # Prints 0xFF0000
```

A couple of important things to note that have bitten me in the past:

1. Make sure your width includes the length of the leading "0x"

   - This is because the `ljust` function operator operates on raw text and doesn't realize it's a hex string
2. If you give a width value shorter than you need, the strings won't be filled up enough and will have different lengths.

   - In other words `len(hex(0xFF0000).ljust(4, '0')) != len(hex(0xFF0000).ljust(4, '0'))` because you need a length of 8 characters to fit both cases

Answer (score 4):

Use the [*format()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) built-in function to show the hex representation to the expected level of precision:

```
>>> format(53, '08x')
'00000035'
>>> format(1234567, '08x')
'0012d687'
```

The [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) `08x` means "eight lowercase hex digits padded with leading zeros".

Answer (score 1):

You say the user typed this input in on the keyboard. That means you *already started with* the strings you want, but you parsed integers out of the input and threw away the strings.

Don't do that. Keep the strings. Parse integers too if you need to do math, but keep the strings. Then you can just do

```
print(original_input)
```

without having to go through a reconstruction process and guess at how many leading zeros were originally input.